# Ionic Angular Capacitor multi select mode to delete items

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to move that this screen (1) to this screen (2), when long press on card.

The idea is to change display to have a multi select card (like Android device when you select multi pictures in your library)

My first idea was to integrate a gesture (for long press) and move to Edit mode where click on card display yellow circle as selected.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Long press gesture is good idea. You can enable a Boolean `isLongPressed` on very first item then click on any item will check if `isLongPressed == true` add selected box on that item (`IsItemSelected` on clicked item) and on confirm button check if `IsItemSelected == true` then delete it. you can use `forEach()` for this.